# Compiling thesis chapters in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, vbscript

I am used to the Latex typesetting where in writing my thesis, I partitioned my thesis into the various chapters and in the end used the \include keyword to compile all my chapters into the master document and also automatically created the table of content.

My question is how can I perform similar operation on Microsoft word. I have already have all the chapters written in separate document files. Does there exist perhaps a VBS code or something else that can perform this and also generate the table of contents. Thank You

PS: I use microsoft office 2016/2019

Comment: Word has built-in tools to create the document with that functionality.  Your thesis is already in Latex with everything it needs to automate the TOC, so you're looking for a way to convert it to what Word will recognize?

Comment: @fixer1234 can you refer me to such tools.

Comment: @fixer1234 my thesis this time is written in microsoft word chapter by chapter

Comment: I haven't used Word in awhile, but just look up how to set up the TOC. My recollection is that it will do the basics very simply, based on heading styles, and you can get fancy using fields.  It doesn't require scripts.  I always worked from a single file so if each chapter is a separate file, you might need to do something to link them.  Word's built-in help goes into a lot of detail.

Comment: You can [merge multiple Word documents into one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/merge-word-documents). Then, [generate a table of contents (TOC) in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-table-of-contents-882e8564-0edb-435e-84b5-1d8552ccf0c0).